# C struct and pointer program does nothing when compiled. Displays no errors or warnings

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have this code and it isn't running for me.  It doesn't give any errors or warnings.  So I don't know what is wrong with it.  I'm not too experienced with pointers in structs and I don't even know if that part of the code is causing it not to run.

I've used both Code::Blocks and DevC++ to compile it but neither worked any different.

It's a little long but it is only 3 functions.  Nothing prints to the screen at all for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo{
        int num;
        char *word;
        struct foo *ptr;
};
void func1(struct foo);
void func2(struct foo*);
void func3(struct foo);

int main() {
        struct foo a;
        a.num = 5;
        a.word ="myword";
        func1(a);
        printf("1 %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);

        a.num = 100;
        a.word = "secondword";
        func2(&a);
        printf("2 %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);

        a.ptr = &a;
        a.num = 50;
        a.word = "mylastword";
        func3(a);
        printf("4 %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);
}

void func1(struct foo a)
{
        while(*(a.word) != '\0');
        {
            putchar(*(a.word));
            a.word++;
        }
        putchar('\n');
        if(a.num % 10 != 0)
        {
            a.num *= 2;
        }
        a.word--;
        printf("num is %d\n", a.num);
}

void func2(struct foo *a)
{
        while(*(a->word) != '\0')
            { putchar(*(a->word));
              a->word++; }

                    putchar('\n');
        if(a->num % 10 != 0)
            { a->num *= 2; }
        a->word--;
        printf("num is %d\n", (*a).num);
}

void func3(struct foo a)
{
        if(a.num > a.ptr->num)
            { a.num = 500; }
        else
            { a.num = a.ptr->num +1; }
        a.word = "myotherword";
        a.ptr->word = "yetAnotherWord";
        printf("3 %d %s\n", a.num, a.word);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you all.

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger.   Using a debugger to step through code is 100% mandatory, especially when you don't understand why its behaving the way it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void func1(struct foo a)
{
    while(*(a.word) != '\0');
```

You should not have a semicolon after the while statement.

When fixed, it prints:

```
[4:58pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo
myword
num is 10
1 5 myword
secondword
num is 100
2 100 d
3 51 myotherword
4 50 yetAnotherWord
```

And to reinforce abelenky's comment, this took 3 seconds to discover with a debugger.

```
[4:59pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] g++ -g foo.cc -o foo
[4:59pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] gdb ./foo
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1752) (Sat Jan 28 03:02:46 UTC 2012)

(gdb) run
Starting program: /private/tmp/foo 
Reading symbols for shared libraries ++......................... done
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
func1 (a={num = 5, word = 0x100000e91 "myword", ptr = 0x7fff5fbffa58}) at foo.cc:34
34      while(*(a.word) != '\0');
(gdb)
```

Comment: _excellent_ demonstration of `gdb`, that's worth its weight in saffron.

Comment: There is an unfortunate trend to do all the fun stuff of designing and getting out all the syntax errors, then trying to turn over the hard, grunt stuff to experienced developers on blogs/groups.  Is debugging even taught in C. Sci. courses today?

Comment: @MartinJames: No unfortunately not, at least not at my uni,  I've only used the debugger in DevC++.  I've heard that's one of the absolute worse choices out there, meanwhile that is exactly what my professor says to compile all our work on.  I've switched over to Code::Blocks within the last month and I haven't gotten a chance to learn to use the debugger, I believe I need to execute commands to get it to debug.  I looked up gdb which was mentioned above, apparently its built for linux (I'm on Windows 7) but I just downloaded MinGw which I just read is supposed to be the Win version of gdb...

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ Express is free and has the best debugger around.

Comment: @markgz:  Thanks I'll check out visual c++ and see how I like the interface.

Comment: @AdamJohnston - then maybe you could change course/uni?  Software development is 10% inspiration and 90% debugging.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program.  Yes, it's really that important!  If there is such a thing as an indispensable developer, it's the guy/gal who can sit there, look at all the evidence and develop some strategy that localizes down a system-wide, intermittent, show-stopping bug and, eventually, surfaces it and fixes it.  If you don't ever want to admit in a progress meeting that you've spent $30M, can't deliver and have no plan, learn debugging!